# Strange Console output when running any project

Tags: spring

As of today, the STS has started displaying strange little question marks throughout its output every time I run a project (any project). I'm not sure why. Does anyone have any clue why and how I can fix it?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it's a space defined in that way

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please.